# Creating an Ipad app with static html,css & javascript

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad

Let me explain the scenario first.

- I have a simple static dashboard html page with 5 simple charts created with HTML5, CSS 
  and javascript.
- It renders data from a static Json to display the charts.
- Its is not online and running in my local system.
- There are no back end code which connects to a database.

Now I want to convert this to an Ipad app where I can see the dasboard page without out internet connection.

Kindly provide me a best way to do this.

Regards,
Shanmugam

Comment: It's called manifest files on html5. Search for on the internet. SO helps  you debug but doesn't write your code ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) (or [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/)) for building native web applications for all major platforms using HTML 5 , CSS and JavaScript.

You can refer to [this Blog](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2012/01/26/how-to-use-phonegap-to-port-quickly-your-web-app-to-a-native-ios-and-android-device/) post on how to easily port existing HTML5 based application to iOS and Android.

Additionally you can also check [this link](http://www.learningsolutionsmag.com/articles/971/development-tips-creating-an-html5-mobile-app-with-phonegap) for some more insights.